# Scheduling a task on python

Tags: python, timer, scheduled-tasks

I want to run a program that runs a function every 4 hours.
What is the least consuming way to do so?

Comment: Least consuming? Please clarify

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it is unix, then the answer is most likely cron...

Comment: What platform? On Unix/Linux, the at/cron mechanism are the right way to do it. On Windows you have to create a service, and register its UUID and arrange for it to be started on boot, and send your firstborn to Redmond, or sumptin like that...

Comment: Why aren't you using `cron` on linux or `at` on Windows?

Comment: well, I am planning to give this software for friends on multiple OS's, so it would have to be none-OS specific.. I see that nobody is stressing that Bryan's answer is fundamentally wrong CPU wise so I'll use his.

Comment: you can also take a look at [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simlest way I can think of (in python since the post is tagged with python):

```
import time

while True:
  do_task()
  time.sleep(4 * 60 * 60) # 4 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds
```

Comment: ok that works very well, however I'm troubled CPU power used, or is it pretty much efficiency proof?

Comment: "efficiency proof?"  What does that mean?  Do you think it uses the CPU while sleeping?

Comment: It's pretty much safe to say that it just puts the process to sleep. Virtually zero CPU use until it wakes up.

Comment: time.sleep() is not accurate. You should use time.sleep() in repeated intervals via a loop to perform a check if the elapsed time meets the expected time. You can use time.time() to get the current time, add the difference to it and then use time.sleep() in a loop to see if time.time() >= expected time. This isn't a suggestion for scheduling but just a simple solution for simple time based delays. For 4 hours, `expected_time = time.time() + (4 * 60 * 60)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sched` module

Here are the docs

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sched.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the build in timer thread:

```
from threading import Timer

def function_to_be_scheduled():
   """Your CODE HERE"""

interval = 4 * 60 * 60   #interval (4hours)

Timer(interval, function_to_be_scheduled).start()
```

Comment: Wouldn't `function_to_be_scheduled` only be run once? And not repeated *every* 4 hours.