# Schedule Python Script to run every Sunday without cron

Tags: python, cron

I have a python file by name Sample.py, which needs to be run once every Sunday irrespective of time. I want the whole script to run, not just one function inside it.

Can this be done without using cron??

I tried searching for solutions, but couldn't find the right solution. Please help me out with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Then basically you want to write your own cron?  Why?

Answer (score 3):

We can use the Python `sched` module and `exec()` the script. Thus given `Sample.py`:

```
print ("Hello World")
```

... we can write another script `sched_sample.py`:

```
import sched, time

dayLen = 86400  # seconds
weekLen = 7     # days

dayLen = 1      # We make the days 1 second long for testing

def onlyOnSunday ():
    tt = time.localtime()
    exec(open("./Sample.py").read())
    t = time.mktime(tt)+dayLen*weekLen
    s.enterabs (t,0,onlyOnSunday)

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
tt = time.localtime()
t = time.mktime(tt)+(6-tt.tm_wday)*dayLen
s.enterabs (t,0,onlyOnSunday)
s.run ()    # Run all scheduled events
```

... which uses the method described in the most recent answer to [Scheduling a task on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852090/scheduling-a-task-on-python) to initially schedule whatever was in `Sample.py` to run, `exec`ing it as described in an answer to [What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0). I'm using Python 3 but if you're using Python 2 you can just use `execfile()` directly.

Before the first call to `s.enterabs()`, we compute how many days are required to get to next Sunday and schedule the first run for then. Subsequently, we just schedule for the next Sunday by adding a week's worth of seconds to the scheduled time. Note that the next time is calculated from the time obtained immediately after `onlyOnSunday()` is first called, so if `Sample.py` takes (say) an hour to run we won't have the scheduled time slipping later in the Sunday.

Of course, the 100% Python solution adds a process to the system that wouldn't be needed if `cron` was used.